# How to correctly set up IntelliJ with WSL2

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am not able to run project created under WSL2. I am getting this  error. Does anyone have idea what could cause it?

```
Abnormal build process termination: 
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 --exec /bin/sh -c "cd /home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server && /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dpreload.project.path=/home/jakub/test -Dpreload.config.path=/mnt/c/Users/Z004506P/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/options -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-636684381209623859 -Djps.in.wsl=true -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2021.1 '-Didea.home.path=/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1' -Didea.config.path=/mnt/c/Users/Z004506P/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1 -Didea.plugins.path=/mnt/c/Users/Z004506P/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/plugins -Djps.log.dir=/mnt/c/Users/Z004506P/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/log/build-log '-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1/jbr' -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.10 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true '-Djava.io.tmpdir=//wsl$/Ubuntu-20.04/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/test_77f155f7/_temp_' -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dtmh.instrument.annotations=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled '-Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\Z004506P\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-13948257364742160812-is-running\"' -classpath /home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/jps-launcher.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher '/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/netty-buffer.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/maven-resolver-transport-file-1.3.3.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/jna-platform.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/oro-2.0.8.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/slf4j.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/log4j.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/lz4-java-1.7.1.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/jna.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/maven-resolver-provider.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/annotations.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/resources_en.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/commons-lang3-3.10.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/util.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.3.3.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/jps-builders-6.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/asm-all-9.1.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/forms_rt.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/guava.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/jps-builders.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/zip-signer.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/jdom.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/intellij-deps-fastutil-8.5.2-6.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/plexus-utils-3.3.0.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/javac2.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/qdox-2.0.0.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/trove4j.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/forms-1.1-preview.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/jps-javac-extension-1.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/aether-dependency-resolver.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/http-client.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/maven-resolver-transport-http-1.3.3.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/idea_rt.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/netty-codec-http.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/jps-model.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/gson-2.8.6.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/platform-api.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/jasper-v2-rt.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/ant-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/java-guiForms-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/eclipse-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/eclipse-common.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/java-langInjection-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/groovy-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/groovy-constants-rt.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/maven-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/aspectj-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/gradle-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/devkit-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/javaFX-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/javaFX-common.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/javaee-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/kotlin-stdlib.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/kotlin-reflect.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/kotlin-plugin.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/kotlin-jps-common.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/kotlin-common.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/javaee-jpa-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/javaee-appServers-websphere-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/javaee-appServers-weblogic-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/groovy-grails-jps.jar:/home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/groovy-grails-compilerPatch.jar' org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 192.168.203.193 57615 867865da-6270-418c-bb35-8dcdf1591467 /home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server"
Build process started. Classpath: /home/jakub/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1/compile-server/jps-IU-211.6693.111/jps-launcher.jar
Error connecting to 192.168.203.193:57615; reason: connection timed out: /192.168.203.193:57615
io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /192.168.203.193:57615
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:261)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Exiting.
```

Comment: Disable the firewall or [set up the rules](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-262876).

Comment: I have already tried that but I am not able to run this command :Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter -Program "C:\users\yole\appdata\local\jetbrains\toolbox\apps\idea-c\ch-0\212.1026\jbr\bin\java.exe" | Get-NetFirewallRule | Where-Object Profile -eq "Public" | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter | Where-Object Protocol -eq "TCP" | Get-NetFirewallRule | Set-NetFirewallRule -Action Allow

Comment: Disabling the firewall will work if you can't set up the proper rule manually.

Comment: That is unfortunatelly not possible because my computer is managed by company and I am not able to turn firewall off. I sould be abble to add rules though. Just the command wasn't working for me. Could you tell me what rules should I add manually?

Answer (score 25):

## Official instructions: wrong or out of date?

The official instructions from JetBrains at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-product.html#debugging_system_settings for configuring the Windows Firewall has two parts

### (Official) Step 1: allow traffic from WSL (this is right)

The first step in the above link is to add a new inbound rule to allow all traffic from WSL (via PowerShell as Administrator):

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound  -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)"  -Action Allow
```

This command works and adds the new rule.

### (Official) Step 2: Remove blocking inbound traffic to IDEA (this is wrong)

The next step in the instructions is to remove the existing rule(s) that block traffic to IntelliJ IDEA:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule | where DisplayName -ILike "idea*.exe" | Remove-NetFirewallRule
```

This command doesn't do anything because the filter part `where DisplayName -ILike "idea*.exe"` does not match anything.

The `DisplayName` property presumably corresponds to the `Name` column in the Firewall control panel:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA rules already in Windows Firewall]

So you can see that "idea*.exe" won't match there.

If I change the search to:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule | where DisplayName -ILike "IntelliJ IDEA*"
```

Then I do get all four rules returned in the shell output:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetFirewallRule | where DisplayName -ILike "IntelliJ IDEA*"


Name                  : TCP Query User{6288ADD6-1B2E-4BFF-9317-AEEA34194E04}C:\program files\jetbrains\intellij idea
                        community edition 2021.2\bin\idea64.exe
DisplayName           : IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2
Description           : IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2
DisplayGroup          :
Group                 :
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Private
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Inbound
Action                : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : DeferToUser
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
Owner                 :
PrimaryStatus         : OK
Status                : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus     : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource     : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType : Local

Name                  : UDP Query User{1AE9E9C6-02EF-4C65-8781-B1050740E936}C:\program files\jetbrains\intellij idea
                        community edition 2021.2\bin\idea64.exe
DisplayName           : IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2
Description           : IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2
DisplayGroup          :
Group                 :
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Private
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Inbound
Action                : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : DeferToUser
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
Owner                 :
PrimaryStatus         : OK
Status                : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus     : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource     : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType : Local

Name                  : {386E3B53-5E4D-4939-8114-74499BDA8515}
DisplayName           : IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2
Description           : IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2
DisplayGroup          :
Group                 :
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Public
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Inbound
Action                : Block
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : Block
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
Owner                 :
PrimaryStatus         : OK
Status                : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus     : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource     : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType : Local

Name                  : {63ED0AB1-12B9-47F2-9810-D1D446EBF9D8}
DisplayName           : IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2
Description           : IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2
DisplayGroup          :
Group                 :
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Public
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Inbound
Action                : Block
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : Block
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
Owner                 :
PrimaryStatus         : OK
Status                : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus     : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource     : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType : Local
```

### Step 2: Remove blocking inbound traffic to IDEA (right)

When I disable those two Public inbound rules, and have the new added WSL inbound rule in place, *then* IDEA can run Java correctly where it was failing with the connection error before.

You can achieve the same disabling/removal of these two inbound Public rules for IDEA by one of the following methods:

#### Option 1: Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security > Inbound Rules

In the view as shown in the image above, right click the rules and select "Disable Rule" for each inbound rule on the Public profile.

#### Option 2: Disable via PowerShell

You can disable the same two rules via PowerShell (as Administrator) with the following command:

```
Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Public | Get-NetFirewallRule | where DisplayName -ILike "IntelliJ IDEA*" | Disable-NetFirewallRule
```

#### Option 3: Remove via PowerShell

You can remove the same two rules via PowerShell (as Administrator) with the following command:

```
Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Public | Get-NetFirewallRule | where DisplayName -ILike "IntelliJ IDEA*" | Remove-NetFirewallRule
```

All three of these methods worked for me and allow me to have all Windows Firewall profiles (Domain, Private, Public) enabled, and Java now runs correctly in IDEA on WSL2 projects located in the WSL2 filesystem.

**Update**: I had to roll back from the latest 2021.2 version to 2021.1.3, because the latest version will "lose" it's ability to connect to the WSL2 filesystem until WSL is restarted.

I have both versions installed, but I had to edit the firewall rules to allow traffic to the 2021.1.3 program (curiously also *named* 2021.2 in the firewall!) and add the Public profile (was just Private) to the Allow rule.

Comment: `Get-NetFirewallRule | where DisplayName -ILike "IntelliJ IDEA*"`
`Get-NetFirewallRule | where DisplayName -ILike "idea*.exe"` both of these output nothing in my system and the error persists any idea why? I cant find anything relating to IDEA in the Windows Defender Inbound Rules as well

Comment: If there are no results for those searches, maybe IntelliJ IDEA no longer adds firewall blocking rules, and just Step 1 to allow traffic from WSL should be enough.

Comment: Tried and doesn't work :'( Thank you though appreciate it

Comment: Option 2 worked for me (I did need to restart IDEA)

Comment: I updated from version .2 to .3. Then the firewall changes did not work. I had to reinstall the new version and now it works

Comment: The name of the .exe seems to depend on the way you install IntelliJ. If you use JetBrains Toolbox to install the IDE, then the IntelliJ binary lives under something like `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\221.5591.52` (depending on the exact version), and the name of the binary is `idea64.exe`. It seems that the standalone installation uses a differently named binary, which would explain the different working setups we can observe...

Comment: I can confirm that these Official powershell commands work. I was having issues with Gradle and IntelliJ IDEA on WSL2 + Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, setting correct Shell path of WSL 2.0 distro in Intelij's terminal settings path helped. Instead of `wsl.exe` set whole path for your distro ( I took path from [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/install)).

In my case, when I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, changing from `wsl.exe` to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

#### Windows 11

1. Search for `Windows Defender Firewall`
2. Press Advanced Settings

[image]

3. Select `Inbound Rules`

[image]

4. Order the list by names
5. Search  for : Intellij IDEA, java, jetbrains_... etc..  (you may not have all exact, the point is to enable anything Jetbrains -related)
6. If the rule appears with a red sign that means that is blocked
   [image]
7. To enable it, select the rule and on the right pane select `Properties`
   [image]
8. Select `Allow the connection` and select `OK`
   [image]
9. Do this for all JetBrains related stuff (and Java related)

Wait some minutes and try again, you may also need to **restart Intellij**

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.
All the mentioned PowerShell commands, including the ones on the JetBrains site, didn't really help.

But what eventually did the trick was that Windows Defender's "Inbound Rules" panel. Had to just find all the Restrictive rules (i.e. the ones with "Action: Block") for both "idea64.exe" and "IntelliJ IDEA" and disable them.

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

**Antivirus Firewall was blocking conection between WSL and Intellij**

In my case I followed the oficial documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-product.html), but it wasn't Windows Firewall which was blocking the access to WSL, it was my antivirus McAfee Security, so I just need to go to **McAffe app -> My protection -> Firewall -> Apps connect to network -> Find Intellij -> Click on Edit and Allow All**. That solve my problem, so maybe it is valid to **check the firewall configuration of your antivirus for Intellij**.

Ps: I'm currently using Win11 and Intellij 2022.3.3