# IntelliJ IDEA setup with WSL2 networking issue

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04LTS for some time now, and there did not seem to be any networking issue (VS code, apt, etc.). Recently, I have tried to set up IntelliJ to work with it, following instructions from [WSL | IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-product.html#crete_project_for_wsl) and [How to correctly set up IntelliJ with WSL2 | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67116880/how-to-correctly-set-up-intellij-with-wsl2). I have also looked at [Add "allow" rule to Windows firewall for WSL2 network | WSL](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4585). I am using IntelliJ 2021.2.3 (also tried with 2021.1.3) and java-17-openjdk-amd64 (2021-09-14).

The networking issue is best illustrated with a piece of code:
`System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName("google.com").isReachable(1000));`

If I run this piece of code from a project in WSL using the JDK in WSL (/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java), then it will always print false; however, if I run it with a Windows JDK then it will also print true.

I have configured the firewall per instructed, specifically:

`New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound  -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)"  -Action Allow`

`Get-NetFirewallProfile -Name Public | Get-NetFirewallRule | where DisplayName -ILike "IntelliJ IDEA*" | Remove-NetFirewallRule`

and allowed it on both private and public networks to no avail. I have also tried the IntelliJ built-in "Fix WSL Firewall Settings" but the issue persists.

Additionally, I am able to establish a TCP connection between my Windows and WSL through port 80 using `netcat`, and able to ping 127.0.0.1 with the code using WSL JDK.

I am at a loss here, and any help would be greatly appreciated!